# How many positive integers less than $2013$ are divisible by none of $2, 3, 4 ,5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

How many positive integers less than $2013$ are divisible by none of $2, 3, 4
,5$?

This was an olympiad question. I thought of writing a number $x \le 2012$ in the form:

$x = 2^{a}3^{b}4^{c}5^{d} = 2^{a + 2c}3^{b}5^{d}$

The number $x$ then must satisfy, $a= c = b = d = 0$

How would I do this? Hints are appreciated?

Comment: By your assumption, $x=1$. Instead, look at odd multiples of $3, 5,$ eliminate duplicates and subtract that count.

Comment: Assumption is wrong, what about x=7

Comment: Do you know about Euler's $\phi$-function? That takes you almost all the way.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, I know of the Totient function, but how does that help?

Comment: The number of integers less than or equal to $2010$ which are coprime to $30$ is $2010 \times  (1 - \frac{1}{2})(1- \frac{1}{3})(1- \frac{1}{5}).$ Then you have to note that $2011$ is coprime to $30$, but $2012$ isn't.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson So that is: $2010(1/2)(2/3)(4/5) = 2010(2/6)(4/5) = 2010(4/15) = 536$ But how does this give the answer?

Comment: @MathGeek-576gamma : It is basically the same as the accepted answer (my comment was being written as the accepted answer was being written). Note that $\frac{4}{15} = \frac{8}{30}$ is the proportion of legitimate residue classes (mod $30$). So 536 integers less than or equal to $2010$ are in the correct residue classes. Then there is $2011$ to include as well.

Comment: Note that "coprime to 30" is the same as "divisible by none of $2,3$ or $5$".

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, By definition? Then if it asked how many integers < 2013 **Is divisible** by 2, 3, 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note the $4$ is redundant. Then, a number $n$ is divisble by none of $2,3,5$ if and only if $\gcd (n, 30)= 1$.

So, $n$ is in a residue class prime to $30$. There are $\phi(30)=8$ of those. So among any conscutive $30$ numbers you have $8$. This gives you the count from $1$ to $2010$. Then check the rest by hand.

Comment: Nice answer, I cant +1 because of a lack of reputation, but what do you mean by "residue class prime.." and there are $8$ of those.. ?

Comment: Okay. So $\phi(30)$ gives the number of positive integers relatively **prime** to $30$ but how does that help what we are doing with $2013$?

Comment: I meant residue classes modulo $30$. If $n$ is not divisible by any of the numbers it is in a residue class modulo $30$ that is prime/invertible to $30$. More concretely, the remainder of $n$ upon division by $30$ must be relatively prime to $30$.

Comment: So what does $\phi(30) = 8$ what does the $8$ mean?

Comment: It means there are $8$ out of the $30$ remainders that are coprime to $30$, namely $1,7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29$.

Comment: You mean, $8$ positive integers $< 30$ so that they are coprime to $30$ ?But how would this help the final calculation? Should I do $\phi(2010)$?

Comment: Yes, $\le 30$ but this is a detail. No you should not compute $\phi(2010)$. You should note that the property of having a $\gcd$ of  $1$  with $30$ is is periodic with period $30$. So, you have $8$ from $1$ to $30$ another $8$ from $31 $ to $60$. Up to $2010$ you thus have $\frac{8}{30}2010$. Also see the comments by Geoff Robinson.

Comment: But the question is, how do you know it is periodic and has the same in each $30$ interval? Excellent answer by the way, it was worth accepting1

Comment: I did do $4/15 \cdot 2010 = 536$ ?

Comment: It is a general property of the $\gcd$ that $\gcd (r , a)= \gcd (r+ a,a)$. Use this for $a = 30$.

Comment: Okay, so and then definition says, if it is coprime to 30 it is comprime to $2, 3, 5$ because. $30 = 2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^1$ ? Also, what if the question asked, how many $< 2013$ ARE divisible by $2, 3, 4$ ? WIll the Totient Function Apply?

Comment: Yes, coprime to $30$ is equivalent to divisibe by none of $2,3,5$. This works because $30 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$ and  $2,3,5$ are prime. // For your separate question. It depends what you mean precisely: if you mean divisible by at least one of the three, then yes these are just the other classes. That statement would be the negation of the one we dealt with so what you find are just all the other numbers.

Comment: Okay, how about $2$ Can you show me how? (Show how many integers <2013 are divisible by $2$) Using Totient specifically?

Comment: There are two remainders $0$ and $1$, or perhaps $1$ and $2$ is nicer. And one of them is coprime to $2$ one is not coprime, so $1$ in $2$ numbers is divisible by $2$. (In this case this is not very interesting though to argue like this.)

Comment: So, $2012/2 = 1006$

Comment: Yes. This is correct.

Comment: I do not understand again the original problem. How is that $30$ periodic? You said find $\phi(30)$ and this is periodic? But how?

Comment: No, $\phi(30)$ is not periodic. The property being coprime to $30$ is periodic: $n$ is coprime to $30$ if and only if $n+30$ is coprime to $30$.

Answer (score 4):

You should ignore the "divisible by $4$", since that is covered by "divisible by $2$". So reword the question as

> How many positive integers less than $2013$ are divisible by none of $2,3,5$?

This is close to a standard combinatorics problem. Find how many numbers are divisible by $2$ (namely $\left\lfloor\frac{2012}2\right\rfloor$), how many by $3$, how many by $5$, how many by both $2$ and $3$, both $2$ and $5$, both $3$ and $5$, and all of $2$, $3$, and $5$. Then use combinatorics to answer the question.

There are other way to answer this, but this way is straightforward, though not the quickest.